# Spring: Is it possible to test transaction rollback in a Test annotated with @Transactional?

Tags: spring, jpa, junit5, spring-transactions, spring-boot-test

I have my integration tests annotated with `@Transactional` so that test data is not actually written into the database.

Now I want to test the transactional behaviour of an implementation:

```
@Transactional
fun update(productTO: ProductTO): Product {
   val product = findProduct(productTO.id).apply { price = productTO.price }
   
   // should rollback
   productPersistence.save(product)

   // when this throws a RuntimeException
   otherService.publishUpdate(product)
}
```

This is the test:

```
@Transactional
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
class ProductTest {

  @Test
  fun `should rollback when sync fails`() {
    
    val product = seedCreator.createProduct()
    assertThat(product.price).isEqualTo(MonetaryAmount("5.00"))
    
    // throw RuntimeException
    Mockito.`when`(otherService.publishUpdate(any())).thenThrow(MyException())

    assertThrows<MyException> {
        sut.update(ProductTO(product.id, MonetaryAmount("10.00")))
    }

    // Verify that update was NOT applied
    // Assertion fails!
    assertThat(productPersistence.find(product.id))
        .isNotNull()
        .extracting(Product::price.name)
        .containsExactly(MonetaryAmount("5.00"))
  }
}
```

I was wondering if a Test that is `@Transactional` itself can test rollback behaviour of a `@Transactional` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the object returned by `seedCreator.createProduct()` is the same as the object returned by `productPersistence.find(product.id)` later in the test.

You need to `refresh` the object using `EntityManager.refresh()` if you want to see its current DB state.

Comment: Calling `EntityManager.refresh()` after `productPersistence.find(product.id)` did not change the outcome.
Just to clarify: The Product created by `seedCreator` has a price of `5.00`, then I'm updating to `10.00`, but throw an exception, so the change should be rolled back so that the price is still `5.00`